# Insert dropdownlist value in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a DropDownList and i have bound it to a table. The problem is when I am trying to insert the selected value of the dropDownlist control into the database, I am not getting the correct values instead getting integer data as 2 and 1.

This is my dropdownList control:

```
<asp:DropDownList
  ID="ddlproductName"
  runat="server"
  DataTextField="Prod_Name"
  DataValueField= "Product_Id"
  >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ddlproductName.SelectedIndex = 0;

  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    tbDate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Product_Id,Prod_Name from Add_Product", con);
      con.Open();
      SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      ddlproductName.DataSource = rdr;
      ddlproductName.DataBind();
    }
  }
}

protected void btnPurchase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    string custName = tbcustName.Text;
    string prodName = ddlproductName.SelectedValue;
    int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(tbQuantity.Text);
    string date = tbDate.Text;
    string voucherNo = tbVoucher.Text;
    double amount = Convert.ToDouble(tbAmount.Text);

    PurchProduct purch = new PurchProduct(custName, prodName, quantity, date, voucherNo, amount);
    ConnectionClass.purchaseProd(purch);
    LblPurchase.Text = "Submitted succesfully";
  }
```

And the purchaseProd method is as follows:

```
public static void purchaseProd(PurchProduct purchase)
{
  cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into TblPurchase(custName, prodName, quantity, date,voucherNo,amount) values (@custName, @prodName, @quantity, @date,@voucherNo,@amount)", con);

  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custName", purchase.custName);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName", purchase.prodName);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", purchase.quantity);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", purchase.date);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@voucherNo", purchase.voucherNo);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount",purchase.amount);

  try
  {
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  finally
  {
    con.Close();
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: ddlproductName.SelectedValue returns your Product_Id. Your Product_Name is bound to ddlproductName.SelectedText.

Comment: When i am using ddlproductName.SelectedText it is giving error which says:'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedText' and no extension method 'SelectedText' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry, that should have been SelectedItem.Text, not SelectedText. You can also get the value using SelectedItem.Value. My bad on getting the property name wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get the product name from selected value , you should bind it as DataValueField not as DataTextField

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your using the Product_ID as the SelectedValue, change the SelectedValue to Prod_Name on your dropdown.